# Appstore Language Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store

My app is available in appstore and its showing localization languages as multiple languages as shown below.

[image]

but I support only one language that is english. In appstore, I have set primary language to English(U.S.) only.

[image]

[image]

how to resolve this? This appears in version 1 of my app. Now I'm going to release my next version. Is it possible to fix in this version before submitting it to app store in itunes connect ?

Answer (score 1):

App Store Localization information of the app is not about the Languages you choose from iTunes. It's about the .lproj folders you have in your project. Remove unused ones.